# PyTorch's nn.Conv2d with half-precision (fp16) is slower than fp32

Tags: python, pytorch

I have found that a single 2D convolution operation with *float16* is slower than with *float32*.

I am working with a Gtx 1660 Ti with `torch.1.8.0+cu111` and `cuda-11.1` (also tried with `torch.1.9.0`)

| Dtype | in=1,out=64 | in=1,out=128 | in=64,out=128 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fp16 | 3532 it/s | 632 it/s | 599it/s |
| Fp32 | 2160 it/s | 1311 it/s | 925it/s |

I am measuring the convolution speed with the following code.

```
inputfp16 = torch.arange(0,ch_in*64*64).reshape(1, ch_in, 64, 64).type(torch.float16).to('cuda:0')
inputfp32 = torch.arange(0,ch_in*64*64).reshape(1, ch_in, 64, 64).type(torch.float32).to('cuda:0')

conv2d_16 = nn.Conv2d(ch_in,ch_out, 3, 1, 1).eval().to('cuda:0').half()
conv2d_32 = nn.Conv2d(ch_in,ch_out, 3, 1, 1).eval().to('cuda:0')


for i in tqdm(range(0, 50)):
    out = conv2d_16(inputfp16)
    out.cpu()

for i in tqdm(range(0, 50)):
    out = conv2d_32(inputfp32)
    out.cpu()
```

It would be great if you let me know whether you have had the same problem, even better if you can provide a solution.

Comment: How are you measuring the time usage precisely? One thing that jumps to mind is that you generally have to call `torch.cuda.synchronize()` before recording the finish time to get a reliable estimate of time utilization

Answer (score 3):

Well, the problem lays on the fact that ***Mixed/Half*** precision tensor calculations are accelerated via ***Tensor Cores***.

Theoretically (and practically) ***Tensor Cores*** are designed to handle lower precision matrix calculations, where, for instance you add the fp32 multiplication product of 2 **fp16** matrix calculation to the accumulator.

As long as GTX 1660 TI doesn't come with ***Tensor Cores***, we can conclude that CUDA won't be able to utilize acceleration with ***Mixed/Half*** precisions on that GPU.